react-spline embed in webflow not working, codesandbox works
I am trying to get a react-spline embed to run in my webflow website. ((I am going that route, because I need to code some interactions with the spline scene for keypresses on my website. Those do not work, if I use the native spline embed that webflow provides.))
I get the scene to work on my codesandbox, yet, when trying to transport that code to webflow, I doesnt work. my wih-think-output would be the scene loading in my "spline-canvas"-div.
Errormessages I get in chrome are:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module // app.js line1
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined // index.js line31
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' // runtime.min.js (splinetool)

Can you guys spot where my thinking and/or knowing is wrong and why it does not work?
Here is my code so far:
websites.html Code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Website</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/index.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-scripts@5.0.1/config/paths.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splinetool/runtime@1.0.94/build/runtime.min.js"></script>
        <script type="module"> import @splinetool/react-spline from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splinetool/react-spline@2.2.6/+esm </script>
        <script src="https://yyg5zc.csb.app/App.js"></script>
        <script src="https://yyg5zc.csb.app/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav> </nav>
        <section>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="wrapper-3d">
                        <div id="root" class="spline-canvas">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

index.js Code:
import "./styles.css";
import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/gWaLjgmepcVMzPkW/scene.splinecode" />
  );
}

App.js Code:
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

Here is a link to a code-sandbox where I got it to post sucessfully:
codesandbox.io/test-react-spline-scene
